# Write a function that puts a 0 in element 1 of an array. Make sure that the function returns null

Tags: element, variable-assignment, execute

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUTyC.png         ...

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, while we'd be happy to help you, we're not here to do your homework. If you have a question about the assignment, or you have an example function with a problem and have a question about that, that would be much more in line with how Stack Overflow operates, but unfortunately just posting a picture of the assignment is not on topic.

Comment: You should take a few minutes to familiarise yourself with the site; [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for example.

Comment: thanks this is not homework. I took on a task from my girlfriend to learn something different. my head been puzzling on this one for a week and tried to find help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function f(nums) {
    if (nums.length > 1) {
        nums[1] = 0
    }
}
```

also if I'm not wrong you cannot define nums as a const as those are unchangeable